# How do I create a user account in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql, security, sql-server-2000

My project needs a SQL Server 2000 User Id and password created for an ASP.NET website. How do I create a user account in SQL Server 2000?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Do you mean creating a new account programmatically? Which language are you using? You can use code to run SQL commands that create an account, assuming you have permissions to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you'll have to run the system stored proc [sp_addlogin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259567(SQL.80).aspx).

See Example "A" in the link.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the SQL-Enterprise manager to create the user accounts and set the permissions for the databases and the access. See this [intro tutorial.](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/sql-server-2000-database#)